# Matlab: Plotting mean along columns, subsetting by running index

Tags: matlab, plot, subset, average

I would like to plot the average of a number of measurements which I have in a long file format with all the measurements in the first columns and the trial number in the second like so:

A=

```
Trial Number   Measurement
1              0.1
1              0.5
1              0.7
1              0.3
1              0.2
2              0.2
2              0.4
2              0.5
...            ...
```

I would like to plot a curve that is averaging over all the trials, so I somehow need to subset according to trial number, then take the mean and plot that. The problem is that the number of measurements per trial are not always the same and that some trials are missing, so the trial numbers are not continuous. Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT: And by "averaging over all the trials" I mean that I would like the average of the first measurement of each trial (here: 0.15), the average of the second (0.45) etc. and then plot the curve following those averages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make an overview of different approaches that may fit your needs:

---

**1) Using [findgroups](https://mathworks.com/elp/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) and [splitapply](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html)**

```
data = readtable('data.txt','HeaderLines',1);
data.Properties.VariableNames = {'Trials' 'Measurements'};

[G,trials] = findgroups(data.Trials);
means = splitapply(@mean,data.Measurements,G);

result = table(trials,means);
result.Properties.VariableNames = {'Trial' 'AverageMeasurement'};

bar(result.Trial,result.AverageMeasurement);
set(gca,'XTick',min(data.Trials):max(data.Trials));
```

**2) Using [unique](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [arrayfun](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)**

```
data = readtable('data.txt','HeaderLines',1);
data.Properties.VariableNames = {'Trials' 'Measurements'};
data = sortrows(data);

trials_uni = unique(data.Trials);
result = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)[x mean(data.Measurements(data.Trials == x))],trials_uni,'UniformOutput',false));

bar(result(:,1),result(:,2));
set(gca,'XTick',min(trials_uni):max(trials_uni));
```

**3) Using [accumarray](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)**

```
data = readtable('data.txt','HeaderLines',1);
data.Properties.VariableNames = {'Trials' 'Measurements'};
data = sortrows(data);

[trials_uni,~,trials_idx] = unique(data.Trials);
result = accumarray(trials_idx,data.Measurements,[],@mean);

bar(trials_uni,result);
set(gca,'XTick',min(trials_uni):max(trials_uni));
```

---

Here is the content of the `data.txt` I used for my tests:

```
Trial Number   Measurement
1              0.1
1              0.5
1              0.7
1              0.3
1              0.2
2              0.2
2              0.4
2              0.5
4              0.2
4              0.1
7              0.8
7              0.4
7              0.5
7              0.4
```

And here is the final output:

[image: Output]

---

If you want the cumulative mean, hwre is how to calculate it:

```
data = readtable('data.txt','HeaderLines',1);
data.Properties.VariableNames = {'Trials' 'Measurements'};
data = sortrows(data);

cm = cumsum(data.Measurements) ./ (1:height(data)).':

plot(data.Trials,cm);
```

If you want to subset the cumulative mean by trial index anyway, you can use one of the previous approaches.

If you instead want to calculate the cumulative mean over each group, you can split your data by indices using one of the method above, and then calculate the cumulative mean over each group.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the different approaches. I learned some new matlab functions today! I've amended by original question to clarify what I need to do, but this has already given me some further ideas.

Comment: Ah ok... you want a cumulative mean then... answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Following ViG's answer, here's something similar using logical indexing. Note that this answer doesn't require the trials to be in order (i.e., it will still work if a result from an earlier trial is recorded some time later in the sequence).

```
trialData = importdata('stack.txt'); 
trials = trialData.data(:,1);        % trails
meas = trialData.data(:,2);          % measurements
uniqueTrials = unique(trials);       % unique list of trials
outputMeans = NaN(length(uniqueTrials), 1);  % initialize output to NaN

% take mean for each unique trial
for ii=1:length(uniqueTrials)
    outputMeans(ii) = mean(meas(trials == uniqueTrials(ii)));
end
plot(uniqueTrials, outputMeans);    % plot
```

Comment: Yeah, this is better. @Algebreaker , take this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much all of you - this has already helped hugely with the subsetting. However I just realised I was being unclear about what I need to average; I've edited my initial post now in the hope of clarification. The measurements for each trial should show a distinctive curve and I would like to get the overall average curve (all trials combined) rather than the mean for each trial. Apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
data = importdata('stack.txt');                                             % import data
trails = data.data(:,1);                                                    % trails
meas = data.data(:,2);                                                      % measurments                                                   
[~,idx] = ismember(trails, trails);                                         % get indices of new trails
trails = unique(trails);                                                    % only save uniques
idx = unique(idx);                                                          % only save uniques
meass = zeros(length(idx),1);                                               % allocate memory

for i=1:length(idx)-1
    meass(i) = mean(meas(idx(i):idx(i+1)-1));                               % save average of each trail
end
meass(end) = mean(meas(idx(end):end));                                      % last trail

plot(trails,meass)                                                          % plot
```